# How to make dynamic li tag with span tag in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one array and i want create li tag with value of array like this example.

```
<ul>
<li><span>amit</span></li>
<li><span>amit</span></li>
<li><span>amit</span></li>
<li><span>amit</span></li>
</ul>
```

i want this with jquery. I don't know more knowledge of jquery. Please give suggestion.

Comment: all span contain amit ???

Comment: yes but data is dynamic.

Comment: i used amit with span tag its data which comes from array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<ul class="mylist">

</ul>

$(document).ready(function(e){
    var ar=new Array("a","b","c","d","e","f");

       var list="";
     for (var i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
        list += '<li><span>' + ar[i] + '</span></li>';
    }
       $('.mylist').html(list);
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Amit12x/nRhHL/1/)

Comment: @Thanks Amit Kumar. but my file is xsl file so i can't use < sign without >.

Comment: i didn't get you here " i can't use < sign without >.". what do you want to say.

Comment: for loop use < sign but xsl file give error for this because its tag starting sign.

Comment: @AmitGujjar This is javascript not xsl so what problem? this should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the `ul` already in your markup:

```
var ul = $("selector for the ul goes here");
ul.append("<li><span>amit</span></li>");
```

(Repeat that second line as necessary.)

It's *well worth* your time to take an hour or two to [read through the jQuery API documentation](http://api.jquery.com). It really only takes that long, and you'll save that much time within just a couple of days, after which it's all profit.

Comment: `(Repeat that second line as necessary.)` Doesn't appending the elements into the dom for every iteration cause performance drawback..?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy: For five items, no. For 10,000, yes.

Answer (score 0):

What you'd want to do is iterate over your array and for each element, append a new `<li>`:

```
var ul_container = $( "#the_ul" );
var items = [ "amit", "yosi", "daniel" ];
$.each( items, function( item ) { // iterate over the array
  $( "li", { // create a new element
    "text": item // define it's text attribute
  } ).appendTo( ul_container ); // append it to the container
} );
```

References:

- [`$.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)
- [`appentTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendto/)